# What is the probability to randomly choose a specific area in a square?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have a square on $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$. That's the $\Omega$.

and we randomly choose a point, $M(x,y)$, in it.

What is the probability that $M(x,y) \in D=\{(x,y)\in \Omega \quad :min(x,y)<\alpha  \}$? $\;\;0<\alpha<1$

My idea was: I tried to calculate the area of $D$, so that my answer will be $\frac{area(D)}{area(\Omega)}$.
My result was: $\frac{1}{(1-\alpha)^2}$

But apparently it's wrong.

The real answer is $\alpha *(2-\alpha)$

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: If you draw a picture of $D$, you will see that the area of $D$ is the area of $\Omega$ minus the area of a square of side length $1-\alpha$. Therefore, $\frac{\text{area}(D)}{\text{area}(\Omega)}=(1-(1-\alpha)^2)/1=\alpha(2-\alpha)$.

Comment: @BrianChao
oh my bad! I accidenlty took the area $(1-a)^2$ as the desired one, instead of substructing it from the $\Omega$.

All clear now. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check what the region $D$ looks like. $D$ is actually the purple region below:

[image]

From here you can then find that the desired probability is

$$\frac{\color{purple}{\text{area}(D)}}{\color{red}{\text{area}(\Omega)}} = \frac{1 - (1-\alpha)^2}{1} = \alpha(2-\alpha)$$

after some algebra.

If you want to play with the Desmos demo that generated the above visual, you can find it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h5f1rqqbtw).

---

*Marking this as Community Wiki since it was answered in the comments while I made the above visual, and I don't really have anything of note to add.*

Comment: thank you for the illustration!
yeah, i was mistaken. i calculated $(1-\alpha)^2$ but i accidently assumed that was the answer instead of substruct it from the $area(\Omega)=1$